# UIPickerView change selected item at runtime

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uipickerview

I have a UIPickerView where I load an NSMutableArray *column in it. In the *column array, I have a few UIImageViews as array's objects. **At runtime, I would like to change the SELECTED item's image ONLY while maintaining the other's item's image. How can I do this?** I can get the row of selected item with:

```
- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
{

}
```

But kinda stuck here. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change your source array and reload that component ( column ) such as :

```
- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
       [column replaceObjectAtIndex:row withObject:[UIImage imageName@"YourImage.png"]];
       [pickerView reloadComponent:component];

}
```

Comment: Hi Ugur Kumru, thanks for the tip! It helps me a lot!
It is not really the precise answer, but I'll accept it as
it helped me to figure it out.

Here's what I used instead since my objects are UIImageViews and not UIImage:

[[self.column objectAtIndex:row] setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Selector2On.png"]];
[pickerView reloadComponent:component];

Comment: Sorry I thought you had the images in your dataSource. Glad it helped.